# How do I loop through multiple tables processing in Python?

Tags: python, loops

I have a block of code I can run without a problem without the loop if I replace "i" for a number. However, I have to repeat this process multiple times (sometimes I have 15 or 30 numbers) so I figure it would be more practical if I could loop it and just change this number whenever necessary. But I have no idea why it is not working.

Here is the code

```
#enriquecimento
import gseapy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nclusters = (3) #numero de clusters
for i in range(nclusters):
    glist[i] = sc.get.rank_genes_groups_df(adata, group = i, key = 'rank_genes_groups_filtered')
    glist[i] = glist[i].head(50)
    glist[i] = glist[i][~glist[i]['names'].str.contains("ASDFASDF", na=True)]
    glist[i] = glist[i]["names"].tolist()
    enr_res[i] = gseapy.enrichr(gene_list=glist[i], organism='Mouse', gene_sets='GO_Molecular_Function_2018', description = 'pathway', cutoff = 0.5)
    enr_res[i].results.head()
    gseapy.barplot(enr_res[i].res2d, title = 'GO_Molecular_Function_2018')
```

And here is the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/data04/projects04/MarianaBoroni/lbbc_members/lib/conda_envs/diogoamb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-b2bd58a0a02b> in <module>
      5 nclusters = 3 #numero de clusters
      6 for i in range(nclusters):
----> 7     glist[i] = sc.get.rank_genes_groups_df(adata, group = i, key = 'rank_genes_groups_filtered')
      8     glist[i] = glist[i].head(50)
      9     glist[i] = glist[i][~glist[i]['names'].str.contains("ASDFASDF", na=True)]

/data04/projects04/MarianaBoroni/lbbc_members/lib/conda_envs/diogoamb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scanpy/get/get.py in rank_genes_groups_df(adata, group, key, pval_cutoff, log2fc_min, log2fc_max, gene_symbols)
     62     colnames = ['names', 'scores', 'logfoldchanges', 'pvals', 'pvals_adj']
     63 
---> 64     d = [pd.DataFrame(adata.uns[key][c])[group] for c in colnames]
     65     d = pd.concat(d, axis=1, names=[None, 'group'], keys=colnames)
     66     d = d.stack(level=1).reset_index()

/data04/projects04/MarianaBoroni/lbbc_members/lib/conda_envs/diogoamb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scanpy/get/get.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     62     colnames = ['names', 'scores', 'logfoldchanges', 'pvals', 'pvals_adj']
     63 
---> 64     d = [pd.DataFrame(adata.uns[key][c])[group] for c in colnames]
     65     d = pd.concat(d, axis=1, names=[None, 'group'], keys=colnames)
     66     d = d.stack(level=1).reset_index()

/data04/projects04/MarianaBoroni/lbbc_members/lib/conda_envs/diogoamb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3022             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3023                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3024             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3025             if is_integer(indexer):
   3026                 indexer = [indexer]

/data04/projects04/MarianaBoroni/lbbc_members/lib/conda_envs/diogoamb/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:
-> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3083 
   3084         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: First, it is not your error, but try no to put the 3 between parentheses (they aren't useful, and make the code confusing, because it looks like a tuple)

Comment: Second, is glist defined ?

Comment: (and if it is, how have you defined it ?)

Comment: Thirdly, what do you mean by "not working" ? Does it run but do nothing ? Does it give an error ? If so, what error ? and on which line ?

Comment: thanks, now that you mentioned it I see the parenthesis are not useful. glist is not defined upstream, it is defined on the code posted. It gets a table in an AnnData object, then I filtered it and turned into a list. I edited the post with the error. Because the error is within the packages I'm not very sure how to interpret it

Comment: OK, now that you have the error code, you have to analyse it: as you can see, the error happens in the sc.get.rank_genes_groups_df function

Comment: are you sure the command `sc.get.rank_genes_groups_df(adata, group = i, key = 'rank_genes_groups_filtered')` works when you replace i with 0 ?

Comment: and by that I mean not `"0"`, or `[0]`, or even `0.`, or  any other thing that looks like `0`, but isn't exactly `0`

Comment: Oh, the original code has "0", because it is a string. This must be it. But I'm still not sure how to correct this. I just tried str(i) but it says "'tuple' object does not support item assignment"

Comment: Yep, this is definitely the problem. Now you just have to lookup how to convert an integer to a string in python

Answer (score 0):

`nclusters` is a tuple, and tuples are immutable. You need to replace it with an integer, which is a mutable  data type.

As you already found out in the comments, the reason for the key error is because the key is a string instead of an integer. Now, instead of calling `sc.get.rank_genes_groups_df(adata, group = i, key = 'rank_genes_groups_filtered')`, you should call `sc.get.rank_genes_groups_df(adata, group = str(i), key = 'rank_genes_groups_filtered')`.

So your final code should be:

```
import gseapy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nclusters = 3
for i in range(nclusters):
    glist[i] = sc.get.rank_genes_groups_df(adata, group = str(i), key = 'rank_genes_groups_filtered')
    glist[i] = glist[i].head(50)
    glist[i] = glist[i][~glist[i]['names'].str.contains("ASDFASDF", na=True)]
    glist[i] = glist[i]["names"].tolist()
    enr_res[i] = gseapy.enrichr(gene_list=glist[i], organism='Mouse', gene_sets='GO_Molecular_Function_2018', description = 'pathway', cutoff = 0.5)
    enr_res[i].results.head()
    gseapy.barplot(enr_res[i].res2d, title = 'GO_Molecular_Function_2018')
```